# Type-level filtering tuple in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3, type-level-computation, hlist, match-types

I've been trying to filter a type-level tuple as suggested by the [Tuple.filter documentation](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/Tuple$.html#Filter-0), but I've been getting the error `Type argument Playground.IsString does not conform to upper bound [_] =>> Boolean`. Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong?

The expected result is that I should be able to write `Filter[("first", 1, "second", 2), IsString] =:= ("first", "second")`

Playground example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SQzB9zTPT5ueIqOiXfG4KQ

```
import scala.Tuple.Filter

type IsString[X] = X match {
  case String => true
  case _ => false
}

abstract class TupleFilter {
  val x: Filter[("first", 1, "second", 2), IsString]
}
```

Comment: It does compile with `type IsString[x] <: Boolean = ...` (see [this example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/e6KsTbVJQTKGnGG52iLbOA)). I'm not sure _why_ this is needed though, hopefully someone can provide an explanation in an answer.

Comment: Ask in the Scala discord channel. It could be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add upper bound

```
type IsString[X] <: Boolean = X match
  case String => true
  case _      => false
```

or add a type lambda into intersection type `& Boolean`

```
val x: Filter[("first", 1, "second", 2), [t] =>> IsString[t] & Boolean]
```

The thing is that currently subtyping rules for match types are the following:

> 1. `S match { P1 => T1 ... Pm => Tm }  <:  T match { Q1 => U1 ... Qn => Un }`
>
>    if `S =:= T`,  `m >= n`,  `Pi =:= Qi` and `Ti <: Ui` for `i` in `1..n`
> 2. `S match { P1 => T1 ... Pn => Tn }  <:  U`
>
>    `U  <:  S match { P1 => T1 ... Pn => Tn }`
>
>    if `S match { P1 => T1 ... Pn => Tn }` reduces to `U`
> 3. `(S match { P1 => T1 ... Pn => Tn } <: B)  <:  B`

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html#subtyping-rules-for-match-types

There is no rule `S match { P1 => T1 ... Pn => Tn }  <:  T` if `Ti <: T` for `i` in `1..n`.

Comment: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/forbidden-to-narrow-a-type-with-match/9167

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/90 https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/8085

Comment: M.Odersky: *"I believe it would be not at all easy to implement since it can cause new cycles. What is the upper bound of a recursive match type?"*