# Scala3 type matching with multiple types

Tags: scala, scala-3, dotty, match-types

I am trying to use a Scala3 type match to achieve something similar to type projections on abstract types in Scala2.

A minimal example is:

```
sealed trait Context

trait AContext extends Context
trait BContext extends Context

trait Data[C <: Context]

case class AData(name: String) extends Data[AContext]
case class BData(age: Int) extends Data[BContext]

type Input[C <: Context] = C match {
  case AContext => AData
  case BContext => BData
}

trait Doer[C <: Context]:
  def doThing(data: Input[C]): Unit

class ADoer extends Doer[AContext]:
  override def doThing(data: AData): Unit = println(data.name)

class BDoer extends Doer[BContext]:
  override def doThing(data: BData): Unit = println(s"age: ${data.age}")

ADoer().doThing(AData("steve"))
BDoer().doThing(BData(40))
```

For some reason, the order of the statements in the type match clause are important. In this case `ADoer` passes the compiler and `BDoer` fails, stating the doThing method does not match the type signature. If the type match clauses puts `case B` first, then BDoer succeeds and ADoer fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not surprising that the order of patterns in pattern matching is important. So it is in match types.

Match types work well on type level. On value level there many limitations

[Scala 3: typed tuple zipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355407/scala-3-typed-tuple-zipping)

[Type-level filtering tuple in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71289032/type-level-filtering-tuple-in-scala-3)

[How to get match type to work correctly in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64434175/how-to-get-match-type-to-work-correctly-in-scala-3)

[Scala 3. Implementing Dependent Function Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486020/scala-3-implementing-dependent-function-type)

[How do you deal with tuples of higher-order types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083142/how-do-you-deal-with-tuples-of-higher-order-types)

[How to prove that `Tuple.Map[H *: T, F] =:= (F[H] *: Tuple.Map[T, F])` in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76029463/how-to-prove-that-tuple-maph-t-f-fh-tuple-mapt-f-in-scala)

[Tuples in Scala 3 Compiler Operations for Typeclass Derivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873631/tuples-in-scala-3-compiler-operations-for-typeclass-derivation)

[scala 3 map tuple to futures of tuple types and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75467905/scala-3-map-tuple-to-futures-of-tuple-types-and-back)

[Express function of arbitrary arity in vanilla Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418623/express-function-of-arbitrary-arity-in-vanilla-scala-3)

[Shapeless3 and annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355212/shapeless3-and-annotations)

[In Scala 3, how to replace General Type Projection that has been dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227132/in-scala-3-how-to-replace-general-type-projection-that-has-been-dropped)

[What does Dotty offer to replace type projections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043630/what-does-dotty-offer-to-replace-type-projections)

Sometimes match types are not so good as input types

```
def doSmth[C <: Context](data: Input[C]): C = data match
  case _: AData => new AContext {} // doesn't compile
  case _: BData => new BContext {} // doesn't compile
```

but ok as output types

```
type InverseInput[D <: Data[?]] = D match
  case AData => AContext
  case BData => BContext

def doSmth[D <: Data[?]](data: D): InverseInput[D] = data match
  case _: AData => new AContext {}
  case _: BData => new BContext {}
```

Sometimes type classes are better than match types

```
trait Doer[C <: Context]:
  type Input <: Data[C]
  def doThing(data: Input): Unit
object Doer:
  given Doer[AContext] with
    override type Input = AData
    override def doThing(data: AData): Unit = println(data.name)
  given Doer[BContext] with
    override type Input = BData
    override def doThing(data: BData): Unit = println(s"age: ${data.age}")

def doThing[C <: Context, I <: Data[C]](data: I)(using
  doer: Doer[C] {type Input = I}
): Unit = doer.doThing(data)

doThing(AData("steve")) // steve
doThing(BData(40)) // age: 40
```

In your specific use case, you can make `AContext`, `BContext` objects

```
object AContext extends Context
object BContext extends Context
type AContext = AContext.type // for convenience, to write AContext rather than AContext.type
type BContext = BContext.type // for convenience, to write BContext rather than BContext.type
```

or classes

```
class AContext extends Context
class BContext extends Context
```

and your code will compile.

The thing is in reduction rules

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html#match-type-reduction

> Match type reduction follows the semantics of match expressions, that is, a match type of the form `S match { P1 => T1 ... Pn => Tn }` reduces to `Ti` if and only if `s: S match { _: P1 => T1 ... _: Pn => Tn }` evaluates to a value of type `Ti` for all `s: S`.
>
> The compiler implements the following reduction algorithm:
>
> - If the scrutinee type `S` is an empty set of values (such as `Nothing` or `String & Int`), do not reduce.
> - Sequentially consider each pattern `Pi`
>
>   - If `S <: Pi` reduce to `Ti`.
>   - Otherwise, try constructing a proof that `S` and `Pi` are disjoint, or, in other words, that no value `s` of type `S` is also of type `Pi`.
>   - If such proof is found, proceed to the next case (`Pi+1`), otherwise, do not reduce.
>
> Disjointness proofs rely on the following properties of Scala types:
>
> 1. **Single inheritance of classes**
> 2. Final classes cannot be extended
> 3. Constant types with distinct values are nonintersecting
> 4. **Singleton paths to distinct values are nonintersecting**, such as **object definitions** or singleton enum cases.

When `AContext`, `BContext` are just traits, then they are not disjoint and the compiler doesn't proceed to the next case.